# Method for displaying an incredibly large image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hoping this isn't too broad of a question for SO, 
but I'm working on a website for an art student who has an 80 foot scroll scanned into three separate .tiff files. I've been searching for a way to display this entire image in a frame. The total file size is approximately 900mb. My general idea is to split the picture into several smaller images and to load each image depending on where it is being zoomed in on.

However, I'm wondering if this type of thing is available already. I remember seeing a website that did something similar to this with a much bigger picture, but I'm having a hard time coming up with solutions for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to present at 100% scale and resolution for some reason?

Comment: You may have luck searching with Google Maps in mind.

Comment: I've seen an [app like this](http://www.maplib.net/) made using [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: @mike well not upfront. but the idea is to be able to get a close look at it, as if you were looking at the actual scroll. So I'd like to be able to zoom in at points and pan etc.

Comment: are we talking about a browser here?

Comment: As other guys are already stating: Google Maps is your best bet. I remember seeing it used for a large game map before. As this example shows, Google Maps is excellent for zooming: http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/

Comment: thanks so much for the google maps suggestions. I'm in the process of making it now. I'll provide an answer for the question when finished.

Comment: @Dave looking forward to seeing it. It seems like a cool project.